# Running Linear Regression model in Apache PredictionIO

Tags: machine-learning, linear-regression, apache-spark-mllib, predictionio

I am trying to run Linear regression model in Apache predictionIo.
and took the sample template from the PredictionIO templere gallery.

https://github.com/RAditi/PredictionIO-MLLib-LinReg-Template

While deploy the engine as a service i am facing the the below issue

> Un Resolved Dependency : Prediction Core_2.10 package not found
>
> sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: io.prediction#core_2.10;0.13.0: not found
>
> [INFO] [Engine$]  at sbt.IvyActions$.sbt$IvyActions$$resolve(IvyActions.scala:313)

Below is the detailed log.

```
 [INFO] [Engine$] [error] (*:update) sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: io.prediction#core_2.10;0.13.0: not found
 [INFO] [Engine$] [error] Total time: 143 s, completed Feb 28, 2019 9:12:35 AM
 [ERROR] [Engine$] Return code of build command: /usr/share/predictionio/sbt/sbt  package assemblyPackageDependency is 1. Aborting.
```

Answer (score 0):

The way you are trying to include PIO is out of data. (it is before it became an ASF project)

You need to use this:
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.predictionio/apache-predictionio-core

```
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.predictionio" %% "apache-predictionio-core" % "0.13.0" % "provided"
```